# PJSIP TLS not working for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, voip, pjsip

I am trying to build a app using PJSIP library.

I am able to establish the connection successfully with UDP and TCP

when Connecting with TLS i receive unsupported Transport error (17160)

please help..

Comment: Here > [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089090/pjsip-tls-not-enable-for-iphone/36897236#36897236) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable TLS transport by using OpenSSL, see:
http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#OpenSSLSuport

If you have problems building openssl, search 'openssl-xcode' in github.

configure:
./configure-iphone --with-ssl=your-openssl-lib-dir

You will see logs if SSL enabled.

Comment: If possible, can you guide me step-step.