# PJSIP TLS not enable for iPhone

Tags: ssl, pjsip, tls1.2

I am trying to build an app which is using `PJSIP` library. I am able to establish a connection successfully with `UDP` and `TCP`. But when trying to connect with `TLS`, I receive the following error: `Unsupported Transport error (17160)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also you need to add the following parameters to your config_site.h.

#define PJ_HAS_SSL_SOCK 1

#define PJSIP_HAS_TLS_TRANSPORT 1

and configure pjsip with --with-openssl=your/opensslDir/path

and then check the log after it finishes configuring.

if you have done everything successfully you will be able to build it without any error.
You can make sure the configuration script was able to detect the openssl libraries, it would look like this : [opensslSupport](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#OpenSSLSupport)

Answer (score 1):

You must build and install OpenSSL for iPhone, then build once again PJSIP libs. [More details](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#OpenSSLSupport)